# Accessing piggybag property from a ExtJs JsonStore, is it possible?

Tags: extjs, jsonstore

Let's say I have a ExtJs Grid that utilizes a JsonStore for a dataset like:

```
{ 
    mode: 'piggy', 
    records: [ 
        {name: 'record1',...}, 
        {name: 'record2',...}
    ]
}
```

rooting at records, the grid displays fine. Now is it possible that I can access the "mode" property from the store object? It contains some metadata about my grid beside the row data, and it certainly seems like a waste to open another Ajax connection to the server to get a metadata value. Anyone has done that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still have access to the raw JSON data that came back in the response. 
There are probably multiple ways to get to it but here is one:

`store.proxy.reader.rawData` or `jsonData`

Comment: Yep! That works! I figured out that the exact solution 5 minutes after my post and mean to replay to my own question, but stackoverflow didn't allow me to reply within 8 hour of my first post.

Comment: it's ok, feel free to accept the answer, it may be useful to someone else too, and you'll gain points by marking accepted answers. you don't get any points for answering your own question though.